# SQLAlchemy: writing to database after the response has been sent

Tags: python, optimization, memcached, data-storage

I have a simple service that does approximately the following:

1. An HTTP client connects to the server
2. The server writes the sessionID of the client and the timestamp to the database, and in most cases just returns an empty response

*(The cases when it does do real work and return actual data are irrelevant to this question)*

In order to return this response as soon as possible, I'd like to write the info to memcache in the request handler's body (because memcache is fast), and to spawn a separate thread where another function using SQLAlchemy will write it to the persistent storage. This way, I'll be able to return immediately after writing to memcache and spawning a thread, and the request handler will not have to wait until SQLAlchemy saves the info to the database.

Does this make sense? If yes, how should I implement it?

Comment: have you benchmarked both solutions (only writing to memcache is relevant for the second one)? My guess is that, if there even is a measurable difference, it will pale against general network latency variance. As a general advice, read the first paragraph on this page: http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?PrematureOptimization

Comment: Will do. But I would still very much like if it is possible to launch a background job in another thread (for cases where the amount of calculations *will* affect the initial delay) and avoid data corruption/inconsistency or other problems usually associated with poor parallel programming skills.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use something like the [Celery distributed task queue](http://celeryproject.org/) to offload processing to other machines. It does require setup of a separate infrastructure, but will allow for tasks to be handed off from web requests for processing in the background, while the HTTP repsonse to the request can be returned immediately.